# How do I properly wire new Honeywell thermostat?

Tags: hvac, thermostat

I’m writing because I’m trying to replace my old Honeywell Thermostat with a new one.
The old labels for the wires does not match what they are asking for with the new one.
I’ve attached a pic of the old one wired up:

[image: old thermostat with labels and wires attached]

And a pic of the new one and the labeled wire terminals:

[image: new honeywell thermostat terminals]

Does anyone know where the wires should go?

Comment: Are you open to taking your new thermostat back and getting a different one instead?

Comment: Have you considered consulting the manual?

Answer (score 1):

Old thermostat is a Honeywell type.

It has an option to control the Fan speed.

New thermostat does not have that.

1 & 2 on the old are 24 Volts = R & RC on the new thermostat.

3 on the old is heating

4 on the old is Cooling

Now you have 4 more wires on the old used to control the Fan speed. Only one wire #9 on the new.

[image: thermostat]